# javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html

i am using javascript to change the text of div tag on run time.

how can this be done..

my div tag is as:

```
<div id="topdiv" style="color:Blue" onmouseover="button1();">
    <input type="button" id="btndiv"  onclick="edit1();"/>
     Div Tag
    </div>
```

i wnt the user to input text on runtime in div and that should be displayed in div. 
can someone help me..

Comment: No, not like that. As @gnur has stated, innerHTML is NOT a Javascript function but a `property` which you have to assign to.

Comment: now i want to change at run time. means as i click on button, a cursor should pop-up and the text should be entered at runtime..

Comment: So do it, and [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try document.getElementById('topdiv').innerHTML = "Hello"

Answer (score 3):

It should be `innerHTML`. `innerHTM` is not a javascript function.

Comment: @kawade: is this a new question?  You'll probably get a quicker answer if you move this comment into a new question.

Answer (score 2):

```
function edit1() {
    alert('you are in edit1');
    document.getElementById('topdiv').innerHTML = 'hello';
}
```

and with proper error handling:

```
function edit1() {
    alert('you are in edit1');
    var topDiv = document.getElementById('topdiv');
    if (topDiv != null) {
        topDiv.innerHTML = 'hello';
    } else {
        alert('topdiv is nowhere to be found in this DOM');
    }
}
```

Comment: now i want to change at run time. means as i click on button, a cursor should pop-up and the text should be entered at runtime..

Comment: @kawade, where should this text by entered?

Comment: dimitrov: when i click button, a cursor should blink on div text and as user edit the text it should be displayed on html page

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't get a magic variable just by having an element with an id. `var something = document.getElementById('some-id')`
2. The property is called `innerHTML` not `innerHTM`
3. `innerHTML` is a string variable not an function. Assign a value to it with `=`, don't try to call it with `()`

Comment: now i want to change at run time. means as i click on button, a cursor should pop-up and the text should be entered at runtime..

Comment: So do it, and [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

To get the `div` you should use `document.getElementById('topdiv')`. There is indeed a WebKit feature, that elements with an ID are automatically expanded as global variables, but it's highly questionable, that this becomes mainstream.

Then, `innerHTM` should read `innerHTML`, and you assign directly:

```
foo.innerHTML = "hi there"
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use

document.getElementById('topdiv').innerHTML = 'hello';

Answer (score 1):

You should use references instead of ID's, using `this`.
In that case `this` means the node that triggers the event.

```
<div style="color:Blue" onmouseover="button1(this);">
    <input type="button" onclick="edit1(this);"/>
    Div Tag
</div>

function button1(divRef){
  //divRef is the reference to the DIV
}
function edit1(inputRef){
  //inputRef is the reference of the INPUT
  //inputRef.parentNode is the reference to the DIV
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function edit1() {
        alert('you are in edit1');
        document.getElementById('topdiv').innerHTML = 'hello';
    }
```

This should work by specifying the id

Answer (score 0):

In standard JavaScript usage you'd do as per @DarinDimitrov 's answer.

```
document.getElementById("topdiv").innerHTML = ('hello');
```

Once you're happy with JavaScript I would suggest you look at the JQuery libraries - the powerful syntax will let you write short, neat code like this:

```
$("#topdiv").html('hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file

```
<div id="topdiv" style="color:Blue" onmouseover="button1();"> Div Tag</div>
<form><input type="button" id="btndiv" value="Edit" onClick="window.open('t2.html','popuppage','width=850,toolbar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=yes,height=700,top=100,left=100');" value="Open popup"/></form>
```

t2.html file

```
function sendValue (s){var selvalue = s.value;window.opener.document.getElementById('topdiv').innerHTML = selvalue;window.close();}

<form name="selectform"><input name="details" value=""><input type=button  value="Copy input to parent opener" onClick="sendValue(this.form.details);"></form>
```

Got Idea from this source [enter link description here](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=35053)